# How to handle setOnClickListener for dynamically added button in android?

Tags: java, android-studio, for-loop, onclicklistener

I have added `button` view to a `linearlayout`
and now I want to `setOnClickListener` on each added `button` here's my code

```
for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
   Button btn = new Button(this);
   btn.setText("button " + i);
   myview.addView(btn);

   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you clicked button " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
}
```

but getting result is only `you clicked button 15` for all buttons, but i want to get only that position result which I have clicked on button Like:

for button1 ==> `you clicked button 1`
for button2 ==> `you clicked button 2`

How to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `setTag` and `getTag` to identify your Buttons.

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("button " + i);
btn.setTag("button" + i);
myview.addView(btn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you clicked " + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: if your intention is to only read out "you clicked button (number)" seems like that is also the text on your button, you can cast the view as a button and do gettext() on it, and then concatenate with "you clicked ". something like this "you clicked "  + (Button) v.getText()

Comment: @Mohammed Abdul Bari, No i can't do that. there button text and button tag values are different